# State-of-the-art methods for out-of-sample-extension

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, out-of-sample, manifold-learning

I'm using a kernel based dimensionality reduction algorithms, and interested in extending out-of-sample data points for further analysis.

I've been using the Nystrom method for this task, and some variants of it (such as ensemble Nystrom method and modified Nystrom method). I know also that there are works concerning the procedure of sampling for the Nystrom method in order to improve performance.

My question is - are there other methods, outside the scope of Nystrom method, that are competitive?